# Header banner in html and css

Tags: css, html

I'm getting frustrated with this responsive web design. I'm trying to create a banner for a one page site that i'm trying to build (for exercise purpose).

Instead of making the image as a background of the header, i wrote it inside the header tag in the html, making it look like a banner is not that hard for me but i wanna put some text on top of the image and it works perfectly fine with absolute positioning of the hgroups.

```css
header#main img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;
    opacity: 2;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header#main hgroup h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
    opacity: .5;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #E7E7E7;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: lighter;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

header#main hgroup h2{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    opacity: .9;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #E7E7E7;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: justify;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 42%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="main">
    <img src="imgs/mountain.jpg"/>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2> subtitle </h2>
    </hgroup>
</header>
```

And when i try to resize the browser they go missing.
Any technique on making a header banner?

Comment: As far as I know the `hgroup` tag has been removed from the W3C spec and is considered, at least by MDN, experimental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into what happens when you place a position:absolute 
element within a position:relative one.  This should give you what you need.

Your positions are currently relative to the whole screen rather than the outer banner area - which means as the screen changes size, the whole thing jumps about regardless of the image height.

If you make the outer element of the banner position:relative, then they will then be in relation to the dimensions of the this banner area, not the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.
https://jsfiddle.net/1c8qy7bo/

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
  <img align="center" src="http://www.improntaunika.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/moutain.jpg"/>
  <h1> AAAAAAAAA </h1>
  <h2>BBBBBBBBBBBBB</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    height: 14%;
    background-position: 100%;
    min-height: 80px;
    min-width: 300px;
}

   img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50px;
   }

h1{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50px;

}
h2{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50px;
  top:50%;
}
```

Comment if you have a question.
I hope this will be usefull.